# Count json tags in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, sum

I have this json strings

```
[{"count": 9, "name": "fixkit", "label": "Repair Kit"}, {"count": 1, "name": "phone", "label": "Telefoon"}]
[{"count": 3, "name": "phone", "label": "Telefoon"}]
[{"count": 5, "name": "kunststof", "label": "Kunststof"}, {"count": 6, "name": "papier", "label": "Papier"}, {"count": 2, "name": "metaal", "label": "Metaal"}, {"count": 2, "name": "inkt", "label": "Inkt"}, {"count": 3, "name": "kabels", "label": "Kabels"}, {"count": 2, "name": "klei", "label": "Klei"}, {"count": 2, "name": "glas", "label": "Glas"}, {"count": 12, "name": "phone", "label": "Telefoon"}]
[{"count": 77, "name": "weed", "label": "Cannabis"}, {"count": 1, "name": "firework1", "label": "Vuurpijl 1"}]
```

And know i want the following output

```
Phone | Number of phones (in this case: 16)
Fixkit | Number of fixkits (in this case: 9)
```

I wanted to do this with a sql query. If you know how to do this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using MySQL 8, this is a bit more complicated. First you have to find a path to a `name` element that has the value `phone` (or `fixkit`); then you can replace `name` in that path with `count` and extract the `count` field from that path; these values can then be summed:

```
SELECT param, SUM(JSON_EXTRACT(counts, REPLACE(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(counts, 'one', param, NULL, '$[*].name')), 'name', 'count'))) AS count
FROM data
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 'phone' AS param
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'fixkit'
) params
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(counts, 'one', param, NULL, '$[*].name') IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY param
```

Output:

```
param   count
fixkit  9
phone   16
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/LfUpfKSH9xixJttvjk649/0)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can unnest the arrays into rows with [`json_table()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html), then filter on the `name`s you are interested in, and aggregate.

Assuming that your table is `mytable` and that the json column is called `js`, that would be:

```
select j.name, sum(j.cnt) cnt
from mytable t
cross join json_table (
    t.js,
    '$[*]' columns(
        cnt int          path '$.count',
        name varchar(50) path '$.name'
    )
) j
where j.name in ('phone', 'fixkit')
group by j.name
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7C56hLWR8ams1FFFXtrypD/0)**:

```
| name   | cnt |
| ------ | --- |
| fixkit | 9   |
| phone  | 16  |
```